# Why is my subnet mask 255.255.255.255?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, subnet

I have a modem which used for internet broadband and I got an IP address in the 'A' class 10.x.x.x and have netmask 255.255.255.255.

- What does 255.255.255.255 mean exactly?
- When I try to sniff with promisc mode, will this 'netmask' never allow me to try such things?
- What is the `dhcpcd` configuration so that each client gets the subnet mask 255.255.255.255?
  (For example: By MAC Address)

Comment: Addressing is no longer classful and the addresses in 10.x.x.x are in a private range.

Answer (score 15):

It means that your phone is using a point to point link.  All your outgoing traffic will be routed to the other end of your link and nothing will be sent to the local network, which is unsurprising as there is no local network.

Answer (score 11):

A network with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.255 puts each device inside its own subnet, forcing them to communicate with the router before communicating with any other device.

Answer (score 2):

An address with a 255.255.255.255 may be one end of a PTP (point to point) tunnel.  Check your routing table using a command like `netstat -rn`.  You may see a route to another address from your IP.  The other address should have a route to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 (the default route).

Answer (score 0):

10.0.1.1 isn't an external IP, it's a LAN, VPS, etc (Hamachi is the main use of it) address. You need a non-LAN global ip address, your router should be doing this as it is your gateway, and you can have a internal IP like yours and still be on the internet, so this isn't your problem. What is your modem? What have you changed since you got it?

Comment: 'and you can have a internal IP like yours and still be on the internet, so this isn't your problem.', how come sir ?               what is my modem? do you mean the vendor sir? my modem is haier C100, i changed nothing just run 'wvdial' in order to established my internet connection on host A ( 10.0.1.1) eth0 ,  really looking forward for your leap of faith of answers sir :D

Answer (score 0):

It probably means you're using PPPoE. PPP links are commonly created using 32-bit netmasks.

It doesn't affect your Internet connection in any measurable way.

Answer (score 0):

That mask means host only address. It means you are on the end of a point-to-point link, and are not routed through.

Answer (score 0):

You might have site site vpn . it will broadcast all interfaces on your roter and your route will decide where to forward the traffic on the remote site

Answer (score 0):

If you are subnet mask such as 255.255.255.255 then your network ID and IP address will be same. Why... because SUB_NET_MASK *and* IP ADDRESS = NETWORK ID, so every device connected to the device will also get network ID as IP address. If A wants to send a message to B, then it will send it to the gateway first and afterwards to B. It's nothing but an end-to-end connection.

Comment: I still don't get what 255.255.255.255 mean!